# Spark batch to migrate data between 2 cassandra clusters

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using spark to move some of the data from one cassandra table to another cassandra table on another cluster.

I specified cassandra config for one of the source cluster with followings:

```
/*
spark.cassandra.connection.host: 
spark.cassandra.connection.port:
spark.cassandra.auth.username:
spark.cassandra.auth.password:
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.clientAuth.enabled: true
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled: true
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path: 
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password: 
spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms: */

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(config.getSourceTable())
            .load();
df.show();

// *** How/Where do I specify cassandra config in destination cluster? ***
df.write()
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(destinationTbl);
```

How/Where do I specify cassandra config in destination cluster (Java Perferred)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but based on the [Russel Spitzer's blog post](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2016/02/16/Multiple-Clusters-SparkSql-Cassandra/) you can do following (not tested in Java, but should work):

- Set 2 configuration options (or add them when creating `spark` instance):

```scala
spark.setConf("ClusterSource/spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
spark.setConf("ClusterDestination/spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.2");
```

- Add into the `options` call the name of the corresponding cluster as a `cluster` entry.

P.S. Also, remember that if you'll need to migrate data and keep WriteTime and/or TTL on the data, then you'll need to use RDD API, as these things aren't supported in the DataFrame API.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use-case, but in my case I was not able to establish a connection to 2nd Cluster using the method Alex suggested due to some connector issue. So, I had to convert this DataFrame to an RDD and use RDD methods to write it to 2nd Cassandra Cluster

Pass all the Cassandra Connector Details to another sparkConfig file and parse it using CassandraConnector.

```
{    
val cluster: CassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(sparkConfig)

      implicit val c: CassandraConnector = cluster

      dataFrame
        .rdd
        .saveToCassandra(keySpaceName, tableName, SomeColumns(ListOfColumns)
}
```